# How can `forP` be executed in an action?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

An action expects a return value of `Action ()`, but `forP` returns an `Action[()]`.
How can it be executed in an action?

Answer (score 3):

If the return value is irrelevant it can simply be ignored:

```
void $ forP commands runCommand
```

Otherwise it can be bound to a variable and used afterwards:

```
values <- forP commands runCommand
return (fold values)
```